# Why is recursion faster when using a global variable rather than a local one for memoization?

Tags: javascript, performance, recursion, memoization

I noticed something peculiar when attempting to speed up a recursive function. When I made the object I was employing for memoization an argument to be passed to the function rather than a global variable, the code execution became considerably slower.

So instead of this:

```
var memoizationObj = {};
function factorial(n) {
  // factorial code
};

var a = factorial(10);
```

I changed the code to this:

```
function factorial(n, memoizationObj) {
  // factorial code
};
var b = factorial(10, {});
```

And the code execution became > 50x slower.

[image: jsperf]

**Why is this happening?** Here is the [**jsperf**](http://jsperf.com/recursion-with-global-obj-vs-arg) with the full code.

Comment: please have a look at this article, it is one of my favorite for writing efficient javascript code: http://oreilly.com/server-administration/excerpts/even-faster-websites/writing-efficient-javascript.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that setUp is only called once for all trials, so with each trial after the first for the global version, you're starting with a full memo. Basically, you only compute the value once and all subsequent runs just return a cached result.

See this version for a better comparison, it resets the global memo on each run of your Global test.

http://jsperf.com/recursion-with-global-obj-vs-arg/2